# Is there any sequence satisfies this :$\exp\left(\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\exp(a_n)$ for which both becames convergents?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I seek an example of a sequence $a_n $ numerical or integers for which both side of (1) is convergent. Is there any sequence satisfies this:$$ \exp\left(\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq0}a_n\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\exp(a_n)\tag{1}$$

What is an example of a sequence which satisfies $(1)$? If no such sequence exists, how can one prove that no such sequence exists?

Comment: but they arn't equal

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ is convergence then $a_n$ converge to zero, but then $e^{a_n}$ converge to 1 so the second sum does not converge.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik yes you are right.

Comment: the other thing that you could ask for is that $\sum a_n \to - \infty$ so that LHS 'is' 0, but as long as each $a_n ≠ -\infty$  $e^{a_n} > 0$ so the two sides don't agree. Incidentally the constant sequence $a_n = -\infty$ is a 'solution'.

Comment: @yanko But if the $\sum a_n$ converge to $-\infty$ this could work, right?

Comment: @ty. if that sum goes to $-\infty$ then it is not 'convergent' in any traditional sense of the word.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't think OP asked for a convergent sequence. He just wants the two expressions to converge and be equal.

Comment: If you only ask for a finite sum, then e.g. $a_0 = 0, a_1 = \log 2, a_2 = \log 3$ is a solution. https://www-users.mat.umk.pl/~anow/ps-dvi/si-krl-a.pdf

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492408/sum-and-product-of-n-natural-numbers-is-equal/

Comment: Write $x_n = e^{a_n}$ and consider the problem on $[0,\infty]$. The only case $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n$ are finite is $x_n \equiv 0$ for all $n \geq 0$. Allowing infinite sums, all the other solutions are exactly those satisfying $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \log x_n = \infty$. For finite sums, any solution $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ of $\prod_{k=1}^{n}x_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k > 0$ can be extended. For instance, one may start from $(x_1)$ with $x_1 > 1$ or $(1,2,3)$.