# How to solve $a_{n+1} = P/(P-1)$, where $P := \prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$.

Tags: recurrence-relations

I really don't know where to start here. I have looked at "Rational Difference Equation" on Wikipedia, but found nothing useful.

The recurrence I am trying to solve is
$$a_{n+1} = P/(P-1), \text{ where } P_{n-1} := \prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i},$$
where $a_{1} \neq 1$.

The motivation for this comes from finding solutions in real numbers to $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i},$$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Of course $(\alpha, \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1})$ is a solution when $n = 2$ ($\alpha \neq 1$). So in general, we can find solutions for any $n$ by choosing $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \ldots, \alpha_{n-1}$ to satisfy the sum/product relation above, and then letting 
$$\alpha_{n} = \frac{\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\cdots\alpha_{n-1}}{\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}\cdots\alpha_{n-1} - 1}.$$
Finding explicitly the $\alpha_{i}$ in terms of $\alpha_{1} =: x$ is equivalent to the recurrence relation above (right?).

**Edit**. As lulu stated, letting $b_{n} := 1/a_{n}$ and $Q_{n} := \prod_{i=1}^{n} b_{i}$, we have $b_{n} = 1 - Q_{n-1}$. Noticing that $b_{n} = Q_{n}/Q_{n-1}$, we get the relation 
$$Q_{n} = Q_{n-1} - Q_{n-1}^{2} = Q_{n-1}(1 - Q_{n-1}),$$

which seems to be the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map). Perhaps there's another way to look at this problem?

Comment: Do you mean to omit $a_n$ from the right hand?  Also, the notation isn't great....$P$ should be $P_n$ or $P_{n-1}$, no?

Comment: If $b_i=\frac 1{a_i}$ and $Q_{n-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}b_i$ then $b_{n+1}=1-Q_{n-1}$ which seems a lot more tractable.

Comment: @lulu Sorry I did not mean to omit $a_{n}$ on the right! So from your second comment, we'd have $b_{n} = 1 - Q_{n-1}$.

Comment: That makes more sense.  I ran a bunch of examples...didn't see any great pattern emerging.  Doesn't prove there isn't one, of course.

Comment: Well, by your remark that $b_{n} = 1 - Q_{n-1}$, and also noticing that $b_{n} = Q_{n}/Q_{n-1}$, we get the relation $Q_{n} = Q_{n-1} - Q_{n-1}^{2}$.

Comment: Well, the [logistic recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) hasn't got a simple closed solution in general.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492408/sum-and-product-of-n-natural-numbers-is-equal/

Comment: @rtybase Hi. Thanks for the reference. Although helpful, I am trying to solve in **real** numbers.

Comment: Integers are still reals ... anyway, up to you.

Comment: @rtybase Right. I would like to find a general solution (I know integers are real numbers...). I will look at your reference in more detail soon.